# Difference between "toString" and "as String" in Dart?

Tags: dart

Is there any difference between `.toString` and `as String` in Dart?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`toString()` is a method on `Object` and is therefore available on every object. The method is used to get a string representation of the object:

> A string representation of this object.
>
> Some classes have a default textual representation, often paired with a static parse function (like int.parse). These classes will provide the textual representation as their string represetion.
>
> Other classes have no meaningful textual representation that a program will care about. Such classes will typically override toString to provide useful information when inspecting the object, mainly for debugging or logging.

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/Object/toString.html

`as String` is a typecast in Dart and is used to tell the analyzer/compiler that whatever it assumes, you are now going to tell it that your object is in fact a `String` at runtime. You can hereafter use the object like a `String`.

But the compiler will add a check at runtime and if the object is not compatible with the interface of `String`, your application will crash because you have lied to the compiler.

It is therefore two entire different things and is used for different purposes. You can e.g. not use `as String` on an object which is not already a `String`.

The safest you can do is just call `toString()` since `toString()` on `String` will just return itself.

Answer (score 3):

They are completely different!

`.toString()` is a method to represent data of a object but `as String` is a type cast which tries to convert the object itself to a `String` .

Imagine you have a class named `Person`

```
class Person {
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  Person(
     this.firstName,
     this.lastName,
  );
}
```

now casting person to a String will lead to an `_CastError` error since Person is not a String or a subtype of String(inherited classes from String class)

```
final person = Person('sajad', 'abd');
final personAsString = person as String;
```

Meanwhile, the method `.toString()` will **represent** you object in a String.

```
final person = Person('sajad', 'abd');
final personToString = person.toString();
print(personToString); // result: Instance of 'Person'
```

`.toString()` is defined for every class in dart and you can override it in you custom classes

for example you can override it in `Person` class to represent firstname and lastname of person

```
class Person {
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  Person(
     this.firstName,
     this.lastName,
  );

  @override
  String toString() => 'Person(firstName: $firstName, lastName: $lastName)';
}
```

And now the result of

```
final person = Person('sajad', 'abd');
final personToString = person.toString();
print(personToString);
```

would be

```
Person(firstName: sajad, lastName: abd)
```